# On projective ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, ideals, projective-module

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring and $I$ be a proper ideal of $R$ and let $b\notin I$ be such that $I+Rb$ and $(I:b)=\{x\in R: xb\in I\}$ are projective as $R$-modules.

Then is the ideal $I$ projective as an $R$-module?

NOTE: If this is true, then it would imply that in a Noetherian ring, if every prime ideal is projective, then every ideal is projective.

Comment: Projective is equivalent to locally free. Try localizing.

Comment: @Mohan: I don't see what happens even if you localize ...

Comment: Once localized, your condition would say $I+Rb$ is free and then by Nakayama, $I+Rb=Rb$. Can you analyze this further?

Comment: @Mohan: I don't get how you concluded $I+Rb=Rb$ (Nakayama !?, can't see that ... )

Comment: @Mohan: hello ... are you there ?

Comment: Did you try to finish what I said? If $R$ is a local ring, $M$ a one-generated module, $N\subset M$ with $M/N\neq 0$, then any element $m\in M$ which generates $M/N$ generates $M$ by Nakayama. Now, take $M=I+Rb, N=I$ and $m=b$.

Comment: @Mohan: but how do I know $I\ne I+Rb$ after localization  ? ($R$ is not necessarily a domain ...)

Comment: If $I=I+Rb$ after localization, then $I$ is projective after localization, which is what you want.

Comment: @Mohan: that's not what I'm saying ... can't it happen that $I_P=(I+Rb)_P$ and $I_Q \ne (I+Rb)_Q$ for two different prime ideals $P$ and $Q$ ?

Comment: Certainly. In the former case, your assumption says $I_P$ is projective. In the latter case, my argument above will imply $I_Q$ is projective. So, in either case you will be done.

Comment: @Mohan: sorry but how does $I_Q+Rb_Q=(I+Rb)_Q=(Rb)_Q$ implies $I_Q$ is projective ? (are you saying that you are not even using $(I:b)$ ?)

Comment: What? You are assuming $I+Rb$ is projective, so $(I+Rb)_Q$ is projective. I did not say then that is equal to $(Rb)_Q$.

Comment: @Mohan: seems to me you did say that $I+Rb=Rb$ after localization ... did you not ? Check your previous comments ...

Comment: Only if $b\not\in I$ after localization.

Comment: @Mohan: now I'm totally lost ... would you mind writing what you're trying to say as an answer (considering this discussion has gone long enough ...) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here goes. To say $I$ is projective is a local condition, so we localize at a prime ideal and call this $R$ etc. Now, one possibility is, when you localize, $b\in I$. Then $I+Rb=I$ is projective since $I+Rb$ is. The other possibility is $b\notin I$. Then, as I explained earlier, $I+Rb=Rb$ and so $I\subset Rb$ and $b$ is not a zero divisor in $R$, since $Rb$ is free. Thus $I=Jb$ where $J=(I:b)$, which is projective. So, $I\cong J$ and thus $I$ is projective. Since at every localization $I$ is projective, so is $I$ without localization.